# Facebook group_id by vanity name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, url

This is an old question, but still no answer on the Internet:

how can one retreive the group id of a Facebook group by it's vanity url  (for example,  https://www.facebook.com/groups/startupmonthly/  ?)

I have to use Open Graph API only - the user provides an url, my server script needs to find the id.

I found no relevant information in the FQL and Open Graph API references.

Somehow services like http://whatismyfacebookid.com/index.php  appear to do  exactly what i need - the question is how?